# Magento 2.3.1 smtp on abstract.php setup

Tags: magento2

In the previous topic :
[Magento 2 smtp could not open socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VHoh.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VHoh.png): [Magento 2 smtp could not open socket](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209227/magento-2-smtp-could-not-open-socket/209246#209246) by akshay billore

I encounter the same issue ,and i tried to do the same solution provided by Dhiren Vasoya.

which is adding code to magento 's abstract.php.but i issue did not resolve and it gives me

(Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 (Connection timed out)
)

[image]

I also tried on gmail smtp using ssl socket as configuration,doesnt work.

Would it be magento version? because i m using 2.3.1,or something else is missing? like openssl configuration?

My openssl:[image]

Comment: did you try below solution ?

Comment: yes ,check the image above.

Answer (score 0):

need to try this.

open this file : vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php

arround line no 267.

```
$this->_socket = @stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
```

comment above line