# HELP! Magento 2 SMTP setup Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate not match

Tags: magento2, smtp

I use Mageplaza SMTP extension to setup the SMTP. When testing the connection, it popped up the follow error. I have already tried some solution online, like trying to modify abstract.php file. There is also an answer saying it maybe caused by shared host, since I am also hosting the website in shared host. But I contacted bluehost, they said my MX is pointing to Google. They won't block anything. Any ideas on this issue? 
php version: 7.1
Magento 2 version: 2.3.2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209246/72911)

You need to try this.

open this file : `vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php`

arround line no 267.

```
$this->_socket = @stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
```

comment above line and add this code below that line.

```
$stream_context = stream_context_create(array(
 'ssl' => array(
  'verify_peer'       => false,
  'verify_peer_name'  => false,
  'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
 ));
$this->_socket = stream_socket_client(
  $remote, 
  $errorNum, 
  $errorStr, 
  self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION, 
  STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, 
  $stream_context 
 );
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. But it is still not working. Do you think it is because of the php version? I am using php 7.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by changing the SMTP host to bluehost (host provider). Looks like the site is not using the gmail host which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use Magepal Extension & ask me if it is not working.

> https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to SMTP host server