# Magento 2.3 forgot password email not sending

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Forgot password email is not sending. I have tried the solution given here [Magento 2 smtp could not open socket](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209227/magento-2-smtp-could-not-open-socket), but it didn't work. I created a simple PHP script to test the PHP mail() function. It is sending mail. But Magento is not sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to install and configure SMTP extension.

**Extension link :**
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

**Configuration link :**
https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-configure-mailcom-smtp-in-magento-2.html

Comment: without smtp also Magento should send mail using PHP's mail function right?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons why the forgot password email may not be sending in **`Magento 2.3`**:

1. Incorrect email settings: Make sure that the email settings in your Magento 2.3 store are configured correctly. **`Go to Stores > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses`** and verify that the correct email address and sender name are set for the "Password recovery email" option.
2. Email server issue: The issue may be with your email server. Check that your server can send emails and that the correct ports are open. Also check your email server's logs for any error messages.
3. Problem with the mail queue: Magento 2 uses a mail queue to send emails, check your mail queue in magento_root/var/spool if there are any files there, you can try to flush the mail queue by running **`php bin/magento queue:consumers:start email.send`**
4. Extension conflict: check if you have any other extension installed that could be conflicting with the email sending process.
5. Email is going to Spam folder: check the email address you used for the test in the spam folder, if the email is there, it means that either the email server or the email service provider is marking the email as spam.
6. Email template issue: check your email template that you are using for the forgot password email, make sure that the template is correct and not missing any variable that would make the email not sending.

It is recommended to check the Magento log files for any specific error messages related to the email sending process, this can help you narrow down the issue.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to be due to the send in blue extension installed in Magento. I have the following in my exception.log `main.CRITICAL: cannot connect to host; error = stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp-relay.sendinblue.com:587 (Connection timed out) (errno = 0 )`

Comment: So your SMTP module not configure properly.

Comment: Have resolved your issue? If not let me know.

Comment: Yes. The server firewall was blocking the access to sendinblue smtp server.

Comment: If my answer helpful please accept my answer.